# How do I change MySQL wait_timeout in production environment at runtime?

Tags: mysql, connections

I'm running Windows, IIS, MySQL, PHP.

In my.ini under [mysqld] the value for wait_timeout is set to 60.

```
wait_timeout = 60
```

But when I execute the following:

```
show variables like 'wait_timeout';
```

It shows me that the value is 28800, which I know is the default.

So I tried to set the value by executing the following:

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 60;
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  MySql Workbench tells me "**0 rows(s) affected**" and when I execute show variables like 'wait_timeout' it still tells me that the value is 28800.

I've also checked interactive_timeout and the story is the same.  The value is 28800 and I can't change it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please check topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425463/set-global-variables-not-working-mysql

Comment: When you want to know value of wait_timeout there are two distinct values.  
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';  and 
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'.  
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout' assumes you are wanting the session variable.
wait_timeout controls inactivity timeout for usual processing, interactive_timeout controls idle time tolerance (seconds) when using MySQL Command Prompt for processing.  When you want to SET SESSION wait_timeout; you need to immediately follow with the request you want to run because a new MySQL command prompt is another session.

Comment: Vince, Great to see you again on SF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set the value without the GLOBAL keyword.

```
SET wait_timeout = 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

`GLOBAL` setting are copied into your `SESSION` settings *when you connect*.  Use either of these syntaxes:

```
SET @@... = ...;
SET SESSION ... = ...;
```

`wait_timeout` refers to how soon before you will be disconnected.  Is that what you want?

Furthermore, there is some confusion over "batch" versus "interactive" timeout.  Good look.

Comment: I was unable to get it to work with the "@@" but using the SESSION keyword was key!  Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent - I do make mistakes.  Fixed.

Comment: Sorry I changed my accepted answer.  I was just reviewing this and realized that although your answer set me on the right path it was not the ultimate solution so I thought for future visitors it would be more helpful to highlight the correct solution with a green check mark.